# Second Instance of Vue Autocomplete does not display array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to add a second instance of Vue Autocomplete to a fiddle:

I renamed the app, model, data, value and options values to app2, model2, etc.

```js
Vue.component("typeahead", VueStrap.typeahead);

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: null,
    options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  }
})

Vue.component("typeahead2", VueStrap.typeahead);

var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data2: {
    value2: null,
    options2: ["qwerty", "apple", "jon"]
  }
})
```

The second instance doesn't work. What is the best way to add a second Vue instance to an app?

Comment: Replace `data2` with `data`, `value2` with `value` and `options2` with `options` and it will work (Vue has no idea what `data2` is)

Comment: So those are reserved words? Thanks. It works now.

Comment: They are not really "reserved words", but when you create a component, Vue looks for a property `data` in the Object you provide to it. If you gave it a `foo` property, or a `data2` property, it would not even look at it

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll leave this up for other beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running two apps and defining the same component twice.  I'm guessing that's not really what you want.  This would make a lot more sense:

```html
<div id="app">
  <typeahead v-model="value" :data="options"></typeahead>
  <typeahead v-model="value2" :data="options2"></typeahead>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component("typeahead", VueStrap.typeahead);

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: null,
    value2: null,
    options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    options2: ["qwerty", "apple", "jon"]
  }
})
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o1hctdeg/)

Comment: That's a better way of doing it. I accepted this answer. I also wanted to know best practices for running two components on the same page.

Comment: I'd go further and define a `typeaheads` array and use `<typeahead v-for="(ta, key) in typeaheads" :key="key" v-model="ta.value" :data="ta.data" />` in markup.

Comment: For two, yes maybe.  For 3 or more, yes probably.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/3r06job7/13/

Following blex's comment, I replaced data2 with data, value2 with value and options2 with options and it worked.

```
Vue.component("typeahead", VueStrap.typeahead);

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: null,
    options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  }
})

Vue.component("typeahead2", VueStrap.typeahead);

var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
  value: null,
  options: ["qwerty", "apple", "jon"]
  }
})
```